# Unable to get required Orientation of arrow

Tags: pstricks

The circle is divided into 8 equal parts and a horizontal and vertical arrow has to be put at the midpoint of each division.

On the right half, the horizontal arrows are directed to right side. On the left half, the horizontal arrows are directed to left side.

On the bottom half, the vertical arrows are directed downwards. On the top half, the horizontal arrows are directed upwards.

I'm able to put an arrow in radial direction. I have trouble placing horizontal and vertical direction arrows.

[image]

### CODE

```
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \pscircle(0,0){4.0}
    \multido{\ix=0+45}{8}
    {
      \rput{\ix}(0,0){\psline(3.9,0)(4.05,0)}
    } 
    \rput{22.5}(0,0){\psline{->}(3.4,0)(4.0,0)}
  \end{pspicture}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I've understood well what you want, here is a short code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,x11names,svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[margin =1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\rvect{\psline[linecolor=LightPink1]{->}(0,0)(0.5,0)}
\def\lvect{\psline[linecolor=HotPink3]{->}(0,0)(-0.5,0)}
\def\uvect{\psline[linecolor=SlateGray1]{->}(0,0)(0,0.5)}
\def\dvect{\psline[linecolor=SkyBlue4]{->}(0,0)(0,-0.5)}

\begin{document}%

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscircle[linecolor =DarkSeaGreen3](0,0){4.0}
\multido{\i = 0 + 45}{8}{\psset{origin = {4 ; \i}}\psline[linecolor =DarkSeaGreen3](-0.1 ; \i)(0.1 ; \i)}
\psset{dotsize = 1pt, linewidth = 1.2pt}
\multido{\n = -67.5 + 45.0}{4}{\rput(4;\n){\rvect}\rput(-4;\n){\lvect}}%
\multido{\n = 22.5 + 45.0}{4}{\rput(4;\n){\uvect}\rput(-4;\n){\dvect}\psdot(4;\n)\psdot(-4;\n)}%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

THE CODE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,x11names,svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[margin =1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\rvect{\psline{->}(-0.5,0)(0,0)}
\def\lvect{\psline{->}(0.5,0)(0,0)}
\def\uvect{\psline{->}(0,-0.5)(0,0)}
\def\dvect{\psline{->}(0,0.5)(0,0)}

\begin{document}%

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscircle(0,0){4.0}
\multido{\i = 0 + 45}{8}{
         \psset{origin = {4 ; \i}}\psline(-0.1 ; \i)(0.1 ; \i)
        }
\multido{\n = -67.5 + 45.0}{4}{
         \rput(4.0;\n){\rvect}
         \rput(-4.0;\n){\lvect}
        }%
\multido{\n = 22.5 + 45.0}{4}{
         \rput(4;\n){\uvect}
         \rput(-4;\n){\dvect}
        }%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Thanks a tonne Bernard. It is your code, I modified a bit to get the required geometry!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's not usual to grab code from other answers to the same question in order to provide an answer

Comment: You can instead propose an edit to his answer by clicking the edit button under his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Saving more keystrokes with PSTricks, just for fun.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}

\psset{linecolor=ForestGreen}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m](-4,-4)(4,4)

    \pscircle{3}
    \multido{\i=0+45,\n=22.5+45.0}{8}
    {
        \psline(2.9;\i)(3.1;\i)
        \rput(3;\n){%
            \psline[linecolor=Magenta]{->}(!\n\space cos 0 lt {-.6}{.6} ifelse 0)%
            \psline[linecolor=NavyBlue]{->}(!0 \n\space sin 0 lt {-.6}{.6} ifelse)%
        }
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]